# phph mysqli Retrieve special characters from database when using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, special-characters

I am converting a php script to use prepared statements.
But when I grab a piece of text from the database, special characters are replaced with a �.

**Example:**

The database contains the following text :
test 'éï' test
(verified with phpadmnin it exists)

```
if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare ( "SELECT act_omschr FROM jag_activiteiten" ) )
{   
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();  
    $stmt->bind_result ( $DBomschrijving );
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ( $stmt->num_rows )
    {
        echo "$DBomschrijving";
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

As a result i get the following: 
test ���� test.

Any way to fix this?

**Edits :**

Changed my database tables to utf8_unicode_ci but it did not fix the issue.
But combined with DDA's awnser below it did the trick.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ( $loginURL, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $database );    
$mysqli->set_charset ( "utf8" );)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the same problem with PDO i use
`$bdd=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_conn;dbname=$database_conn","$username_conn","$password_conn");
$bdd->EXEC('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`

... but your database has to be in utf-8

Comment: Thanks,
In object oriented style it looks like this:

     $mysqli = new mysqli ( $loginURL, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $database ); 
 $mysqli->set_charset ( "utf8" );

Comment: Thanks. Happy to see i could have help you. By the way, PDO is also an Oriented Object style.